# Как правильно использовать условие `if`

Tags: python

Пользователь вводит три числа в одну строку через пробел. Если все числа больше 10 и первые два числа делятся на 3, то вывести `yes`, иначе - `no`.

Входные данные: `15 21 40`. Результат работы: `yes`

Входные данные: `22 25 40`
Результат работы: `no`

```
a, b, c=map(int, input().split())
if a / 3 and b / 3 and c > 10 and a > 10 and b > 10:
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")
```

Как ни стараюсь, всегда выдает `yes`

Comment: Вы пишете a/3 это значит вы хотите поделить a на 3, но не присваиваете результат деления никакой переменной, значит он бесполезен. Используйте (a % 3) == 0, чтобы проверить делимость на 3

Comment: А сейчас в вашем коде выводится YES, если все 3 числа больше 10

Comment: Вы пишите: "Входные данные 22 25 40 Результат работы no". Это неправда. В данном случае тоже будет "yes".

Comment: a / 3 and b / 3 замените на a % 3 == 0 and b % 3 == 0

Comment: @Glebium это как должно быть, тесты для проверки

Comment: bool(a / 3), а также bool(b/3) всегда будет True если a и b > 0. Если же a и b = 0, то будет False

Answer (score 1):

Ошибку уже описали выше)

Вот готовый код с вложенным if для Вашего же понимания;)

```
a, b, c=map(int, input().split())
if a > 10 and b > 10 and c > 10:
    if a % 3  == 0 and b % 3 == 0:
        print('yes')
    else:
        print('no')
else:
    print('no')
```

Comment: Смысл вложенного if?

Comment: @Стас, более читабельный код и возможность лучше отследить ошибки)

Comment: if not a % 3 and not b % 3:

Comment: @Glebium, каждому своё.
Новичкам же нужно доступным языком это показать)

Comment: Согласен, но это так, к сведению, чтобы он разобрался как это работает :)

Comment: Огромное спасибо!